# Erros in importing and reading Excel file in Java code

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to import and read an excel file in my Java code using Eclipse. Following are the errors: The method `createFormulaEvaluator()` is undefined for the type `Object`, Can only iterate over an `array` or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`. Can someone please help me where am I making a mistake? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!! P.S: I am a beginner in programming.

```java
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;  
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
  
public class ReadExcelFileDemo  
{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  
    {  
        //obtaining input bytes from a file  
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\shahk\\desktop\\Test_ReadExcelInJava1.xls")); 
 
        //creating workbook instance that refers to .xls file  
        HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);   

        //creating a Sheet object to retrieve the object  
        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);  

        //evaluating cell type   
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
        for(Row row: sheet)     //iteration over row using for each loop  
        {  
            for(Cell cell: row)    //iteration over cell using for each loop  
            {  
                switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellTypeEnum())  
                {  
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:   //field that represents numeric cell type  
                        //getting the value of the cell as a number  
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t\t");   
                        break;  

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:    //field that represents string cell type  
                        //getting the value of the cell as a string  
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");  
                        break;  
                }  
            }  
            System.out.println();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Following is the `.JAR` file for `Cell.java` that I currently have:

```java
package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel;

public class Cell {

        public static final String CELL_TYPE_STRING = null;
        public static Object CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC;
    
        public String getNumericCellValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    
        public String getStringCellValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

}
```

Following is the file for `FormulaEvaluator.java`:

```java
package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel;

public class FormulaEvaluator {

    public Object evaluateInCell(Cell cell) {       
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to override key core Apache POI classes like `Cell` or `FormulaEvaluator` ? Why aren't you using the built-in ones?

Comment: By the built-in ones, do you mean JExcel ?? Or if not, can you suggest me the specific ones ?? Thanks for your time and comment!!

Comment: "[`JExcel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JExcel) support is discontinued as of May 31, 2020."